# my stand alone laptop

Tags: password, administrator

I have a Lenovo think pad with Ubuntu 14.04 installed I set a new password to the administrator account and I forget what that is. I can use the machine but making changes it asks for the password in which I forgot it. Is their a back door or a way to change it?

Answer (score 1):

The password that you set-up on installation process is the password of your account, not the administrator account.

In normal cases, you can change your password using `passwd`, but since you forgot the password for your account, so you need to log in as the root account.

http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-recover-root-password-under-linux-with-single-user-mode/

Follow above link and do processes. When you change password, put `passwd *youraccount*` command.